# How do I configure nginx to accept gzip requests?

Tags: nginx, gzip, request

I know that you can use [nginx HttpGzipModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule) to gzip *responses*. Can you als use it to enable nginx to handle gzip-compressed *requests*, i.e. ones with the request header: `Content-Encoding: gzip` ?

Note: Apache, with the help of `mod_deflate` can handle gzip-compressed requests with the directive [`SetInputFilter DEFLATE`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html#input).

#### Related

http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,96472,214266

Answer (score 7):

I just tried this on an nginx server I have sitting in front of an Apache backend.

```
curl -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" --include -d @testfile.gz http://example.com/upload_file.php
```

curl automatically added:

```
Expect: 100-continue
```

to the request headers.

nginx sent back a

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
```

response and curl followed up by sending the gzipped data.  nginx passed the whole lot back to Apache, still compressed and still with the `Content-Encoding:` header intact.

If I didn't add the `Content-Encoding: gzip` header with curl, I didn't get the HTTP 100 response but everything else was the same.

This doesn't answer your question yet but it does imply that nginx either doesn't handle this by default or doesn't uncompress the body of the request when it is proxying.  I'm interested in the answer to this one so I'll see if I can try it out on a non-proxying nginx server a bit later on.

Presumably you could solve the bandwidth problem by proxying those requests to an Apache backend with mod_deflate but that ignores the reason you chose nginx in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried on a non-proxying nginx server?

Answer (score 4):

Just found this article: [Howto make Nginx decompress a gzipped request](http://www.pataliebre.net/howto-make-nginx-decompress-a-gzipped-request.html#.Vfgvnp2qqko)

It looks good, but I haven't tried it yet. Hope it helps.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, please [provide context around links](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) so others will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. If possible summarise or quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score -2):

I found good steps on digital ocean for [Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-the-gzip-module-to-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Its good

Comment: Hi, link only answer tend to die with time, please post and quote the step, and make a link to it is a better way to answer there. Thanks !

Comment: Before I wrote wrong link. Now I have updated correct link.

Comment: This is for response compression, not request compression.